# PHP Getting my servers ip/hostname with Cloudflare?

Tags: php, cloudflare

So, okay I want to only accept requests from my web host to my server, I only want to allow either my servers domain name, or my servers ip my server also uses cloudflare.

So I only want to grant access to one or more of my servers & using CloudFlare at the same time, how might this be approached?

Comment: Are you using CF or PHP?

Comment: CF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830782/in-coldfusion-is-there-a-way-to-determine-what-server-the-code-is-running-on, PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408996/best-way-to-get-hostname-with-php

Comment: @JohnConde mikeB I ment cloudflare the DDoS protection reserve proxy for nameserver service..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable, using `SERVER_NAME`;

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

As described in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> 'SERVER_NAME'
>   The name of the server host under which the current script is executing. If the script is running on a virtual host, this will be the value defined for that virtual host.

You are, however, reliant on a server config file (`httpd.conf`) to achieve this.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.com
    UseCanonicalName on
</VirtualHost>
```

The UseCanonicalName directive seems to be on to solve a known bug ([More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name)).